# Add Reviews form in WooCommerce user account dashboard

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to create a form reviews on woocommerce account user? Users select the product that has been purchased then he fills reviews.

Can anyone tell me how? Either use the default rewiews from woocommerce or other plugins.